# Getting issue while automating SOAP service using Karate framework

Tags: automated-testing, soapui, web-service, karate

I am a bit stuck while automating SOAP service . I have below url and request xml :

```
Background:

url 

 Scenario: soap 1.1

request
 """ 


When soap action '********'
Then status 200
```

After running it through Karate i am getting below issue :

```
18:07:52.413 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - 
status code was: 500, expected: 200, response time: 1088, url: :
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body><s:Fault>
<faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">
a:ActionNotSupported</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">

The message with Action '*********' cannot be processed at the receiver, 
due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.
This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver)  
or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.
Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding
(including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).
</faultstring></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Karate is working fine. Look at the error message that has come from the server and work with someone from the dev team. All the best.